# In Java, inside a static method, what is the way to determine which class the static method was called on?

Tags: java, class, subclass

Suppose you have a class and a subclass in Java:

```
public abstract class Car {

    public static Car getCar() {
        Car car = makeCar();
        return car;
    }

    private static Car makeCar() {
        //bunch of code that makes the car
        return car;
    }

}

public class Ferrari extends Car {

    private static makeCar() {
         //bunch of code that makes a Ferrari! Yeah!

         awesomeRide = new Car();
         return awesomeRide;
    }

}
```

Then in another class you call:

```
Ferrari.getCar();
```

Ferrari's super-class's getCar() *and* makeCar() methods will be called. Ferrari cannot @Override getCar() because in Java, static methods cannot be overridden.

So in the Car's getCar() method, how can I tell whether the method call was sent to the class Ferrari, as opposed to the class, Car? Since it's a static method, I cannot do `if(this instanceOf Car)` obviously.

---

EDIT: The correct answer (below) showed me that indeed I can't tell *from within Car* if getCar() is being run due to someone calling Car.getCar() or Ferrari.getCar().

But what I didn't know was that according to Java's documentation, while a static method cannot be overridden in Java, it can be **hidden**.

The key difference between hiding and overriding is that with hiding, static methods call *other static methods on the same class,* not the subclass they got routed in from.

What that means is that with overriding, if these were not static methods, Ferrari's makeCar() would always get called from Car's getCar() method anytime the caller called myFerrariInstance.getCar(). However with hiding, Ferrari's makeCar() will never get called from Car's getCar() method, *because makeCar() is also a static method on the same class.*

Comment: You can't, and I don't see any good reason to want to. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This is strange: the abstract class Car (OK) should not make a makeCar public. Apparently, car making is the responsibility of subclasses, and they may call a makeCar to get the basic object, to be decorated with the make's niceties. For this, making getCar and makeCar protected would eliminate the issue of who's been calling them.

Comment: I suggest looking into Java Generics as it appears that is what you're trying to do - generalize the car so you can concrete them with actual types like Ferrari.

Comment: @JBNizet You asked what I was trying to achieve. I needed to fix a bug in Android where Apache Xalan tries to load XMLEntities.properties by calling PropertyResourceBundle's getBundle method, see the pull request linked below. I'm new to Java and did not know how method hiding worked. This question led me to the answer and I was able to fix the bug. It was a problem because objection throwing causes memory leaks in Objective C, and this is for Google's j2objc project.  https://github.com/google/j2objc/pull/731/commits/6c3141349c3ad2a2a3cc3388c432679dc651d134

Comment: @laune You are correct, makeCar() should be private. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So in the Car's getCar() method, how can I tell whether the method call was sent to the class Ferrari, as opposed to the class, Car

You can't. (I thought `javac` *used* to generate the same bytecode for both calls - it now doesn't, but I don't believe there's any way to detect which call is made at execution-time, and I wouldn't be surprised if it still lost that information during JITting.)

If you feel you *need* to do that, you should change the design - either significantly, or just passing in the relevant class as an argument to the method.

You *could* give each of your subclasses a static method with the same signature. This wouldn't be overriding, but it would work - you'd end up calling the right method, which could then do what you wanted. But if you created a new subclass and forgot to add the method, it would just silently call the superclass one...

Comment: I just checked. It doesn't generate identical bytecode. The bytcode remembers that the method is called on Car or on Ferrari. If it has been called on Ferrari, and Ferrari is later modified to include a getCar() method, then that method will be called without needing to recompile the calling code.

Comment: SO what you're saying is that Ferrari can have its own getCar() method? I thought that you could not override static methods in Java.

Comment: @CommaToast: You can indeed give each of your subclasses its own method. It won't be overriding as such, but it would work. I've edited my answer to indicate that. I'd advise against it though.

Comment: @CommaToast you can't override a static method, but you can hide it with a method with the same signature.

Comment: That's odd because when I tried that, it seems that the method on the super class gets called. For example if I gave Ferrari a method called makeCar() and then called getCar() on Ferrari, the makeCar() that always gets run is the one on Car, and not the one on Ferrari. Maybe it's because Ferrari doesn't have its own getCar(), so the one on Car gets called, and then the runtime thinks that its makeCar() is calling the getCar() of Car and not of Ferrari. Hmm.

Comment: Indeed Java's documentation at  states: "The version of the hidden static method that gets invoked depends on whether it is invoked from the superclass or the subclass." So, Ferrari needs to have its own getCar() if it ever wants its makeCar() to get called if someone else calls Ferrari.getCar()... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Comment: @CommaToast: Yes, `Car.getCar()` will always call `Car.makeCar()`, even if there's a `Ferrari.makeCar()`. The "context" of the call is lost...

Comment: The correct answer not "You can't." but rather, "You can if you add a getCar() method to Ferrari class." Then when it gets called on Ferrari class, you'll know because the getCar method in Ferrari will run instead of the one in Car. This is due to the fact a subclass's static methods hide the super-classes, which is the key information I needed to know. If you reformat your answer to make that last paragraph front-and-center, and remove the "You Can't, then I'll mark you as correct. Also please mention the link I posted above that talks about hiding.

Comment: @CommaToast: You can't do what you asked, which is detect a superclass static method being called "via" a subclass. You can add your own subclass methods to work around that, but that's not what you asked. Read your question again - that's what I answered.

Comment: Ah good point. I can't detect it *from within Car*. Indeed, that's how I phrased my question. Marking you as correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one actual method, so there is no way to know which class you specified in your source (without reading the source)  What you can do is hide the original method though this is generally a bad idea.

If you want to use the class to create a car of that type you can use the constructor

```
Car car = new Ferrari();
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned it is not clear what do you want to achieve and maybe you should re-design your code.

Similar to your code (as far as i understand), would be something like:

```
Ferrari ferrari = Car.create(Ferrari.class);
```

Which could be achieved with following simple example:

```
/**
* @author ben
*/
public class TestClass
{
    public abstract static class Car<E> { 

       private Car() {}
       protected abstract void build();

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return getClass().getSimpleName();
       }

       public static <E extends Car> E create(Class<E> p_class) throws Exception {
           E car = p_class.newInstance();
           car.build();
           return car;
       }
   }

   public static class Ferrari extends Car<Ferrari> {
       protected Ferrari(){};
       @Override
       protected void build() {
           //your bunch of code ...
       }
   }

   public static class Mercedes extends Car<Mercedes> {
       protected Mercedes(){};
       @Override
       protected void build() {
          //your bunch of code ...
       }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

       Ferrari ferrari = Car.create(Ferrari.class);
       Mercedes mercedes = Car.create(Mercedes.class);

       System.out.println("CAR1:" + ferrari);
       System.out.println("CAR2:" + mercedes);
   }
}
```

But there are also many other ways...
As said, it's not clear what do you want to do.

Cheers.